# What is a good CMS to use for a Location Based Directory?

Tags: content-management-system, directory, location

I am looking to create a site that contains a directory of places.  Each place will include all the basic address information (Street, City, State, etc), and a short description.  The end user will be able to search the directory by State, Zip Code, etc.  I was wondering what you would recommend as the best CMS to tackle this?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: This is too subjective. *Any* CMS will accomplish what you need, and "best" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: I guess the question would be, which CMS would be the easiest to set up out of the box?  Or if you have multiple recommendations I would like to hear as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/taxonomy)  with taxonomy.

Or simply create a new content type in Drupal as `Place`. Define fields as State, City, Zipcode, etc. I haven't tried but, i assume Drupal does search in custom fields too.